# PHP need Help iterating through dynamic child nodes

Tags: php

I have to read through different xml files that I pull in and each one has different node names and a different number of children I need to loop through.

Some xml files will only have parent - child while others will have parent - child - grandchild

I was thinking I could create an array for each type of file something like:

```
$nodenames = array(
            '$xml->parent' => '$parent',
            '$parent->child1' => '$child1',
            '$child1->grandchild' => '$grandchild'
            );
```

but I cant figure out a way to create the needed output for:

```
//loop through parent
        foreach($xml->parentnode as $parent){
            
            //loop through first child
            foreach($parent->child1 as $child1){
                
                //loop through second child
                foreach($child1->grandchild as $grandchild){
            
                }
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: You can try use `array_walk_recursive` . See here - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: Or you see here - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct.php

Comment: I can loop through the array fine, I am just not sure how I can build the foreach using the array element names.